# What performance tradeoffs exist between various clojure matrix libraries?

Tags: performance, matrix, clojure, jvm

There are a number of matrix libraries out there for clojure:

- [vectorz-clj](https://github.com/mikera/vectorz-clj)
- [clatrix](https://github.com/tel/clatrix)
- [parallel colt](https://sites.google.com/site/piotrwendykier/software/parallelcolt)
- cerebro

What are the performance trade-offs between these libraries?
I've heard that with some of the underlying implementations, there are trade-offs between (for-example) matrix instantiation and operation performance, but I haven't been able to find a comprehensive resource detailing these considerations.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to make use of `core.matrix`, there are only two implementations at present that are reasonably mature and performant:

- `Clatrix` - uses calls to **native BLAS**
- `vectorz-clj` - a flexible and fast **pure-JVM** implementation

It really comes down to your use cases. If you mostly care about big linear algebra operations and don't mind the native dependencies, then `Clatrix` is your best bet at present - simply because BLAS implementations are so fast. This is particularly useful for:

- Large matrix multiplication
- Linear algebra (matrix decompositions etc.)

If you want to do general array-programming work, then `vectorz-clj` has the advantage of being pure JVM code and much more flexible in terms of array/matrix formats. Examples of things that vectorz-clj supports well that you can't do in Clatrix:

- N-dimensional arrays
- Various specialised types of sparse arrays (diagonal matrices, different sparse storage formats etc.)
- Arrays with arbitrary strided access (like Numpy)
- Lightweight "views" into larger arrays

Overall, `vectorz-clj` won't be as fast for things like big matrix multiplication, but is probably faster than `Clatrix` for many other operations and small/medium sized vector work. I'd normally choose `vectorz-clj` unless I thought that linear algebra performance would be the main bottleneck.

The other `core.matrix` implementations are less mature, but may still be useful for specific use cases. A nice feature of `core.matrix` is the ability to mix and match implementations while using the same common API, so it's not an "all or nothing" choice.

**Disclaimer:** I have created or contributed to many of the above projects. I hope I've given a fairly unbiased and objective evaluation.

If you don't need `core.matrix` support, then you have many more options - you can use any of the Java matrix libraries via Clojure's Java interop. In theory, these could become `core.matrix` implementations as well - the only constraint is that someone needs to do the work to extend the core.matrix protocols to support the new matrix types.

Comment: Thanks! I'm definitely inclined to stick with core.matrix for precisely the "mix and match"-ability you mention.

Also, thanks for all your hard work on these!